# I have a while loop for a game that won't work for some reason

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am having trouble with making this while loop work, any help/advice would be much appreciated.

here's the loop (its not the full program):

```
import random

while your_health or enemy_health >= 10:
    print("He is still attacking you.")
    print("you may either:"
          "a-dodge"
          "b-attack back")
    fight_choice_1_1 = input("What do you do?")

    if fight_choice_1_1 == "a":
        d20_1_1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        if d20_1_1 >= 10:
            print("you dodge the attack")
        elif d20_1_1 <= 10:
            your_health -= knife_damage
            print("you get hit")
            if your_health <= 0:
                print("you lose. :(")
            elif enemy_health <= 0:
                print("you win!")

    if fight_choice_1_1 == "b":
        d20_1_1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        if d20_1_1 >= 10:
            print("you get out of the way and hit him")
            enemy_health -= sword_damage
        elif d20_1_1 <= 10:
            print("he hits you, but you get a hit in too")
            your_health -= knife_damage
            enemy_health -= sword_damage
            print("you get hit")
            if your_health <= 0:
                print("you lose. :(")
            elif enemy_health <= 0:
                print("you win!")
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "won't work". What is the expected behaviour and what happens instead?

Comment: Remember to select the answer that is most helpful to you (click on the green checkmark by it).

Answer (score 9):

Rather than:

```
while your_health or enemy_health >= 10:
```

I think you mean:

```
while your_health >= 10 or enemy_health >= 10:
```

What you have is proper *English* as in "while (your health or enemy health) is greater than ten" but the syntax of computer languages is a little more strict.

To the computer, that means "while (your health) or (enemy health is greater than ten)" and, in the context of a truth value, many languages will simply treat a non-zero value as true. Python *does* follow that convention.

From [5.10 Boolean operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#booleans) of the online Python docs:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are **interpreted as false:** False, None, **numeric zero** of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). **All other values are interpreted as true.**

(my bold). So the statement:

```
while your_health or enemy_health >= 10:
```

is effectively (assuming that it's numeric and you never let it drop below zero in your code, reasonable assumptions given its intended purpose):

```
while (your_health > 0) or (enemy_health >= 10):
```

In other words, the loop will continue as long as your player has *any* health, rather than ten or more health points.